# If $G$ is a group, $H \leq G$ and $K \leq G$, then $HK \leq G \iff HK = KH$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

**PROBLEM**

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$.  Prove that $HK = \{ab | a \in H, b \in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK = KH$.

**WHAT I KNOW**

**(1)** If $H = \{e, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$ and $K = \{e, \beta, \beta^2\}$ are subgroups of $S_4$, one can show that $HK \neq KH$.  We can compute $HK$ and $KH$ to verify that:  In general, the product of two subgroups of a group $G$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

**(2)** If $H = \{h_1, h_2, \ldots, h_r\}$ and $K = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_p\}$ are subgroups and one of $H$ or $K$ is normal in $G$, then (a) $HK = KH$, and (b) $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

**(3)** If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$, so also is $HK$.

**QUESTION**

> How do I then solve the problem at hand, given that what I know seems to require that at least one of $H$ or $K$ is normal in $G$?  That is, how does one prove the statement in the **PROBLEM** section in full generality (without requiring that one of $H$ or $K$ is normal in $G$)?

Comment: You will not need any of the above knowledge. Just show that if $HK = KH$, then $HK$ is a subgroup (what do you have to check here?) and show that if $HK$ is a subgroup, then $HK = KH$ (hint: inversion).